# How do I force a 24 hour format on all time values?

Tags: iphone, nsdate, locale, uidatepicker

Is there a locale (or any other code) that will force all my formating and my uiDatePicker to always be in English and 24 hour format?
I need this regardless of what the device settings are.
many thanks...

Comment: Your question should be titled in the form of a question.

Answer (score 3):

For the `UIDatePicker`, there isn't a way within the SDK to make the component 24 hour (aside from the user selecting a locale in Settings.app which uses 24 hour times). What you'll need to do is roll your own using a `UIPickerView` and a custom data source, which is really quite simple, and then convert the values there into an `NSDate` using simple arithmetic.

For the time formatting, you can always choose what format you want to display `NSDate` objects by using a `NSDateFormatter` like the following:

```
NSDateFormatter *formatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[formatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss Z"];
NSLog(@"the current 24hr date and time is %@", [formatter stringFromDate:[NSDate date]]);
[formatter release];
```

You can then wrap this into Utils class or what have you, and use it globally to format your dates into strings.

Comment: Thanks bensnider, thats annoying about the datePicker, as far as formatting goes, I still get the time in 12hr with AM/PM even when I use HH, if the device (iphone) 24-Hour Time is set to 'OFF' ?

Comment: I have seen comments like:  "if you want to force it to 12-hour mode, regardless of the user's 24/12 hour mode setting, you should set the locale to en_US_POSIX". Is there an equivalent locale for 'always' 24 hours?